# Getting primary key or any other attribute just after inserting a row

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, insert

I have a table with a primary key,  two foreign keys and other attributes. I want to insert a row in a way that just after insertion it should return the PRIMARY KEY, I am using following statement to execute query

```
int MyId = (int)insert.ExecuteScalar();
```

but above code is returning one of foreign keys, which is part of insert query. How can I get primary key in return after insertion? Second, is there any way to get any specific attribute just after insertion.
I am using asp.net and Sql Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a table like this in SQL Server:

```
create table test
(
 id int identity primary key,
 data nvarchar(255)
)
```

You can use [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx): (error checking left out, etc)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace sqltest
{
  class Program
  {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        SqlParameter id = new SqlParameter("id",0);
        //parameter value can be set server side and will be returned to client
        id.Direction=ParameterDirection.Output; 
        string query="Insert into test values ('hello world');select @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
        int lastID=0;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("put your connection string here"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                comm.Parameters.Add(id);
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //id.Value now holds the last identity value
                lastID = Convert.ToInt32(id.Value);
            }//end using comm
        }//end using conn
       }//end Main
    }
}
```

But honestly I would recommend if at all possible you use an abstraction (Linq2SQL, Entity Framework, NHibernate, etc, etc) for this kind of thing because it frees you from having to deal with this kind of boilerplate.

Comment: It gives InvalidOperationException "String[0]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0." at comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: @Rahman my apologies the original code contained a missing `{`, I have updated with a full working console app sample you just need to change the connection string.

Comment: In query "@id" is correct syntax using asp.net? or can you write only insert query with SCOPE_IDENTITY(), which I can execute in Sql Server to see either my query is right or not (I am using SCOPE_IDENTITY() first time)

Comment: @Rahman not sure I understand the question but you can use it in any .net application that uses SQL Server (`System.Data.SqlClient`), be it Winforms, ASP.NET, WPF, etc. You can also use it directly in SQL Server in e.g a stored procedure.

Comment: I am stuck here "lastID = Convert.ToInt32(id.Value);" it says invalidCastException......:(

Comment: @Rahman - that cast assumes that the identity is being correctly returned and the parameter value is not `null`, etc - can you check in the debugger? It runs just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

use output !!

```
create table mytab(
      pk int identity primary key,
      data nvarchar(20)
    );
    go

    insert into mytab
    output inserted.pk
    values ('new item my PK');
    go
```

Comment: how to store result of "output inserted.pk" in a variable using asp.net