# InvalidCastException in getting primary key just after inserting row

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I am using following query to insert a row, I got row inserted but I want to get Primary Key in return of insertion. Row is inserted successfully but getting primary key is giving me hard time. Everything goes fine but at `lastID = Convert.ToInt32(Id.Value);` it says InvalidCastException. The question "[Getting primary key or any other attribute just after inserting a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703191/getting-primary-key-or-any-other-attribute-just-after-inserting-a-row)" is also related to this question

Note: the primary key column name is "Id" and it is of int type, I am doing this in asp.net

```
        SqlParameter Id =new SqlParameter("Id" , SqlDbType.Int);
        Id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        //conn.Open();
        //int inserted = 0;
        //int lastID = 0;
       string insertOffer = "INSERT INTO Offers (userId, column1, column2, column3)  
       VALUES (SomeINT, 'abc', 'abc', 'abc');select Id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
       int lastID = 0;
       using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connection))
       {
           conn.Open();
           using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(insertOffer, conn))
           {
               comm.Parameters.Add(Id);
               comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
               lastID = Convert.ToInt32(Id.Value);
           }//end using comm
       }//end using conn
```

Comment: Try replacing `select OfferId=SCOPE_IDENTITY()` with `select @Id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Comment: using ``select @Id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()`` instead of ``select Id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()`` helped me, Thanks @Milen